# Is there a way to export arbitrary named exports from a typescript declaration file?

Tags: typescript, webpack, css-loader

When using css-loader@6.7.1 with css modules enabled and `namedExports` on, is there a way to wildcard import the file in Typescript and have the resulting type of each named export be a string?

```js
// webpack.d.ts
declare module '*.module.css' {
  export = Record<string, string>; // still contains the default export.
}
```

Edit: Ideally, there wouldn't be a `default` export present on the module when importing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare exports that way since they disabled arbitrary expressions [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#arbitrary-expressions-are-forbidden-in-export-assignments-in-ambient-contexts). Instead declare and type a const and export it.

```js
declare module '*.module.css' {
  const value: Record<string, string>;
  export default value;
}
```

As far as I could find there is no way to have named exports declared arbitrarily. But you could just use the [shorthand ambient module declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#shorthand-ambient-modules) and declare the module twice. It does mean you won't get entire type safety since this will make all named exports `any` but I couldn't find anything else.

```js
declare module '*.module.css'
declare module '*.module.css' {
  // this type is from react-scripts https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-scripts/lib/react-app.d.ts
  // it is better since the data is immutable
  const classes: { readonly [key: string]: string };
  export default classes;
}
```

And in another file

```js
import { someclass } from 'some.module.css';
// ^ typeof any
```

I believe the best solution if you really want strict type safety is to have a build-step that generates a .d.ts for all the css modules.

- https://github.com/Quramy/typed-css-modules

> ```js
> .SomeComponent {
>   height: 10px;
> }
> ```
>
> becomes
>
> ```
> declare const styles: {
>   readonly SomeComponent: string;
> };
> export = styles;
> ```

Comment: It was definitely unclear from my question, but I'm looking for named exports, not a default export of an object.

Comment: Yes, as far as I know there is no way to have arbitrarily declared named exports. They must be explicit. I believe this is the same reason interfaces cannot be arbitrarily mapped. I propose to either use [shorthand module declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#shorthand-ambient-modules) merged with a regular declaration, but the type of the named exports will be `any` instead of `string`. The alternative is to use a library to generate .d.ts files based on .css files. If you don't want a default export you can export default never instead.